# What would you call someone who isn't what people think they are?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an essay about a character within a story arguing that they are different from what people think they are.

The context is the character is Mayella Ewell in *To Kill a Mockingbird* and I'm trying to explain that she isn't as cruel as the trial makes her out to be. I considered *innocent* but that doesn't seem exactly fitting for her.

One word preferred.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. Perfect. She is misunderstood by people who are just into appearances.

Comment: may be reckless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of Travesty by [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/travesty):

> verb
>
> 1. represent in a false or distorted way.
>
>    "Michael has betrayed the family by travestying them in his plays"

You could say that the court trial *travesties* Mayella Ewell's character.

Comment: Apparently it ***is*** a verb- That doesn’t mean I have to like it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Such a person will often claim to be (or be said to be) **misunderstood**.

From [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misunderstood), sense 2 informed by sense 1:

> misunderstood ...adj.
>
> 1. Incorrectly understood or interpreted.
> 2. Not appreciated or given sympathetic understanding: 'a sorely misunderstood child.'

Comment: Misjudged, then.